# moving files in several branches in mercurial

Tags: mercurial

I'm trying to find out how to move several files in mercurial from one directory to another in all branches at once. 
The idea is that i have some files in a directory

a/some_file

which should be moved to

b/a/some_file

but do this in the branchstructure

```
 10   9
 |    |
 |    8
 |    |
 |____/
 7
 |
 ...
```

to keep in mind is that some of the files in node 9 already have changed but should also be moved upwards one directory.
Also I would like to add some files at node 7 so that they exist in both branches. But the important thing is to move the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renames propagate across merges, so if you check out the files at changeset 7, rename them *there* and then merge the rename change to the rest of the branches, Mercurial should do the right thing.

See for example what happens in the following trace of commands. I start by creating a test repository:

```
saturn:/tmp$ hg init test
saturn:/tmp$ cd test
```

Then, I make sure that a file called 'foo.txt' exists at the toplevel directory on a branch called `br.7`:

```
saturn:/tmp/test$ echo foo > foo.txt
saturn:/tmp/test$ hg commit -Am 'add foo'
adding foo.txt
saturn:/tmp/test$ hg branch br.7
marked working directory as branch br.7
(branches are permanent and global, did you want a bookmark?)
saturn:/tmp/test$ hg commit -m 'br.7 opened'
```

Then I fork two other branches, `br.8` and `br.9` from the latest changeset of the `br.7' branch:

```
saturn:/tmp/test$ hg up -C br.7
0 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
saturn:/tmp/test$ hg branch br.8
marked working directory as branch br.8
(branches are permanent and global, did you want a bookmark?)

saturn:/tmp/test$ hg commit -m 'br.8 opened'
saturn:/tmp/test$ hg up -C br.7
0 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
saturn:/tmp/test$ hg branch br.9
marked working directory as branch br.9
(branches are permanent and global, did you want a bookmark?)
saturn:/tmp/test$ hg commit -m 'br.9 opened'
```

Now the changeset graph looks like this:

```
saturn:/tmp/test$ hg log --graph --style=compact
@  3[tip]:1   f3f155b61aa8   2013-01-09 23:48 +0100   gkeramidas
|    br.9 opened
|
| o  2   ad3b03105da7   2013-01-09 23:48 +0100   gkeramidas
|/     br.8 opened
|
o  1   9cfed898c77b   2013-01-09 23:48 +0100   gkeramidas
|    br.7 opened
|
o  0   9a6f15da68d7   2013-01-09 23:47 +0100   gkeramidas
     add foo
```

So if I try renaming the file in branch `br.7` first and then merge the rename upwards, here's what happens:

```
saturn:/tmp/test$ hg up -C br.7
0 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
saturn:/tmp/test$ mkdir subdir
saturn:/tmp/test$ hg rename foo.txt subdir/foo.txt
saturn:/tmp/test$ hg commit -m 'Rename foo.txt'

saturn:/tmp/test$ hg branches
br.7                           4:d57b57b98f19
br.9                           3:f3f155b61aa8
br.8                           2:ad3b03105da7
default                        0:9a6f15da68d7 (inactive)
```

Then, finally, I merge the rename changeset from branch `br.7` to the *higher* branches:

```
saturn:/tmp/test$ hg up -C br.8
1 files updated, 0 files merged, 1 files removed, 0 files unresolved
saturn:/tmp/test$ hg merge br.7
1 files updated, 0 files merged, 1 files removed, 0 files unresolved
(branch merge, don't forget to commit)
```

and the result of the merge looks like this in git-style diff output:

```
saturn:/tmp/test$ hg diff --git
diff --git a/foo.txt b/foo.txt
deleted file mode 100644
--- a/foo.txt
+++ /dev/null
@@ -1,1 +0,0 @@
-foo
diff --git a/subdir/foo.txt b/subdir/foo.txt
--- /dev/null
+++ b/subdir/foo.txt
@@ -0,0 +1,1 @@
+foo
```

If I commit this change, the history now looks like this:

```
saturn:/tmp/test$ hg log --graph --style=compact
@    5[tip]:2,4   22b095e35b43   2013-01-10 00:02 +0100   gkeramidas
|\     Merge rename of foo.txt
| |
| o  4:1   d57b57b98f19   2013-01-09 23:49 +0100   gkeramidas
| |    Rename foo.txt
| |
| | o  3:1   f3f155b61aa8   2013-01-09 23:48 +0100   gkeramidas
| |/     br.9 opened
| |
o |  2   ad3b03105da7   2013-01-09 23:48 +0100   gkeramidas
|/     br.8 opened
|
o  1   9cfed898c77b   2013-01-09 23:48 +0100   gkeramidas
|    br.7 opened
|
o  0   9a6f15da68d7   2013-01-09 23:47 +0100   gkeramidas
     add foo
```

Notice how the rename looks like a real actual 'merge' operation now, and see how log --copies can go back through the rename operation to the original change that added `foo.txt` in this output:

```
saturn:/tmp/test$ hg log --copies --style=compact foo.txt subdir/foo.txt
4:1   d57b57b98f19   2013-01-09 23:49 +0100   gkeramidas
  Rename foo.txt

0   9a6f15da68d7   2013-01-09 23:47 +0100   gkeramidas
  add foo
```

This way, you can have a single changeset (changeset d57b57b98f19 in this example) that does the rename operation at the oldest possible place, and you can merge this changeset to all *upper* branches too. You'd still have to do each branch separately, but I like the idea of being able to track all of: what was renamed, who did the rename, when it happened *and* when it was merged to a derivative branch.